# jquery autosuggest from remote procedural call

Tags: java, jquery, rpc

I've to implement an autosuggest on a textbox whose values are stored at remote server and I'm fetching it using Remote Procedural call in JAVA.

I know the following syntax of ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Employees/SearchEmployees",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        searchText: request.term
    },
    success: function (data) {
        response($.map(data.employees, function (item) {
            return {
                label: item.name,
                value: item.id
            };
        }));
    }
});
```

I'm very much new to remote procedural call and can't figure out what should be the url while making ajax call when I'm fetching the values from remote machine as, it's just a procedure.

Comment: The url `/Employees/SearchEmployees` you have specified will point to `localhost/Employees/SearchEmployees` without any other specification in this code. If so, that url it's correct.

Comment: Can you add jsfiddle link with your sample json data?